# Angular2-google-maps create html-markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, typescript, angular

I am working on a angular2-google-maps implementation, and now I want to create html markers is this possible? Or maybe an other solution of printing `locations.id` in the markers setup like this:

```
locations = [
{id: '1',  lat: 51.5239935252832,    lng:  5.137663903579778,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '2',  lat: 51.523853342911906,  lng:  5.1377765563584035,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '3',  lat: 51.5237298485607,    lng:  5.137969675407476,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '4',  lat: 51.52355628836575,   lng:  5.138066234932012,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '5',  lat: 51.52340275379578,   lng:  5.138211074218816,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '6',  lat: 51.523199152806626,  lng:  5.138382735595769,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '7',  lat: 51.5229955509073,    lng:  5.138511481628484,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '8',  lat: 51.52280529912936,   lng:  5.138543668136663,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '9',  lat: 51.523596340777075,  lng:  5.138463201866216,   content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '700',lat: 51.523372714362736,  lng:  5.1386992362595265,  content: 'Kids Jungalow (5p)'},
{id: '101', lat: 51.52329594683302,  lng:  5.138838711128301,   content: 'Kids Jungalow Giraffe'}
];
```

I tried this but this will only print 1 to 9 :

`<sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="#location of locations" [latitude]="location.lat" [longitude]="location.lng" [label]="location.id">`

Here is a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/djvrrBxov2Pq83DihC22?p=preview)

So basically what I want to do is this :

[image]

Comment: I see 11 markers on your map, matching your 11 locations.

Comment: @duncan yes? but I want to create a html marker or something where the id is printed in the marker

Comment: @duncan can you help me out with this

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it's just using the built-in Google icons for A-Z and 0-9. You can see that in Angular2's own example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview  if you change the label on any of these to '10', it just displays the marker with label 1.  As their GitHub page says, "This project is currently in alpha state. Please do not use this in production."

Comment: @duncan Yes I know, but do you maybe know a way to create an html in angular 2. Where I can set the number of the id in it?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options. One is to use SVG to draw shapes in Marker, and use title to render numbers/text. Second is to implement OverlayView https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#OverlayView which is more advanced approach but gives you more control and responsibility :)